# How can I circumvent wiring all inputs to ports in Quartus 2 schematic block diagram?

Tags: digital-logic, schematics, quartus

I am trying to create a 32-bit adder in Quartus 2 block diagram by stringing 2 12-bit adders and an 8-bit one together. I have created the symbols (components) for the smaller adders already.

I created an array input by naming two input ports A[31..0] and B[31..0]. Now I have to connect the appropriate inputs to the ports of my 12-bit and 8-bit adders by adding wires and naming the wires like A[I] or B[I]. But this seems like cumbersome algorithmic work.

Does Quartus offer a feature to automate/facilitate this process? Like is there any way to create a bus and connect it to the array input and have it generate separate wires for each index of A and B? Or is there any way to write a script to automate this work?

Comment: Probably not. That's why this kind of work is normally done in HDL (Verilog or VHDL) rather than block diagram. Then it's just a few lines of code.